# Bejeweled Twist clone for Gnu/linux

Tags: games

What is The best Bejeweled Twist clone for Gnu/linux. I know about like Kdiamond and Geweled,  but those games are don't have sound or good graphics. I know One good Bejeweled Clone for Gnu/Linux Hotei Jewels Relax but that wasn't a Bejeweled  Twist clone.
F.I.Y I only run thing natively in Gnu/Linux And I don't use Compatibility layers or emulations over they are buggy and they don't use the Gnu/linux file hierarchy.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bejeweled Twist worked just fine under Wine for me when I tested it.

I can't suggest any clones, because to my knowledge there are no Bejeweled Twist clones as yet on Linux. Bejeweled Twist is still a bit new, and so you need to give it some time before anyone attempts to clone it. There is also a risk of a clone being shut down, since Popcap is now run by EA (and EA doesn't like clones).

Your best bet is to give in and use Wine (as I said, it worked fine for me when I tested it).

---

Also, you said Gweled doesn't have sound, but it does, and so does Kdiamond IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

Bejeweled is available as an app for Google Chrome (which also runs on Chromium), as well as being available as completely platform-independent HTML5 content:

http://bejeweled.popcap.com/html5/0.9.12.9490/html5/Bejeweled.html